# Netbeans Application properties access

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Can I somehow access theese properties in java code?

[image]

I figured out only *vendor* & *version* so far:

```
getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVendor()
```